# Convert System.Double[] to Python

Tags: python, python.net

I have a .NET assembly created by our software group that is returning numerical data of the type System.Double[].

What is the appropriate way to convert this into a Python type (list?) so I can create a dict from it?

Ben

Comment: Did you find an answer? I got the same problem when trying to plot a CLR array of double with matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to loop through the object row by row and append to the list.

So if your System.Double[] object is called myData, create a new list called myData_list, loop through myData and append to the list row by row. Try the example below. You can then convert the list into a df and plot it however you see fit.

```py
myData_list = []
for row in myData:
    myData_list.append(row)
```

or using List comprehension:

```py
myData_list = [row for row in myData]
```

I use this method in my application. I am using python net to access the methods in a windows .dll file and this is how I have been able to access the data.

Comment: Will this actually handle the conversion for the .Net types to Python types, in particular for those doubles?

Comment: It does in my application. I am using python net to access the methods in a windows .dll file and this is how I have been able to access the data.

Comment: So this solution is well tested, then. Thanks for the clarification. +1

Comment: No problem. I should have probably added that I was using the method successfully in my answer.

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify how this addresses the question? This doesn't seem to convert *anything* from .Net to Python – at most it converts from Python to Python. It would work with *any* iterable, and is basically a convoluted way of writing ``myData_list = list(myData)``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, the question states that he wants to be able to convert the data into a list. In the situation where I have encountered this exact problem, I am unable to access the System.Double[] object directly, but I am able to iterate through it (the specifics of why are unknown to me) to create a list which allows me to access the data. I found this out when working on the problem in this question. In the question, the object channel_names is a System.Double[].

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69845872/net-methods-in-python-conversion-from-matlab-code-delsys-emgworks)